# ajax validation for multiple instance of model in Yii

Tags: model, yii, multiple-instances

I have two models namely acl and user. Each have there own set of validation rules. I however use all input fields within one form.

In the UserController I have two ajax validation methods within the createAction method

This looks like this

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
            $model=new user;
            $acl = new acl;


            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed

                    $this->performAjaxValidation1($acl);

                    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);



            //$this->performAjaxValidation1($acl);

            //$valid=$model->validate();
            //$valid=$acl->validate() && $valid;



            if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['acl']))
            {
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['user'];
                    $acl->attributes=$_POST['acl'];
                    if($model->save() && $acl->save())
                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
                    'acl'=>$acl
            ));
    }
```

AjaxValidation

```
 protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
            {
                    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                    Yii::app()->end();
            }
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param CModel the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation1($acl)
    {
            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
            {
                    echo CActiveForm::validate($acl);
                    Yii::app()->end();
            }
    }
```

Only one form is validating 
can anyone sugges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `CActiveForm`'s `validate()` [documnentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#validate-detail), you can pass an array of models. You only need to declare one ajax validation function. Below is the modified code

Controller Action

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
            $model=new user;
            $acl = new acl;


            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed

             $this->performAjaxValidation(array($acl,$model));//pass the models as array







            if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['acl']))
            {
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['user'];
                    $acl->attributes=$_POST['acl'];
                    if($model->save() && $acl->save())
                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
                    'acl'=>$acl
            ));
    }
```

Ajax Validation function

```
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
            {
                    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                    Yii::app()->end();
            }
    }
```